# SELECT ... FOR UPDATE in package Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I created PACKAGE and PACKAGE BODY for update statement,

I did not find anything in the StackOverFlow about this,
I wonder if the way I did this is good,
and whether you would change anything.

if I call the procedure

```
begin
account_api.upd_account(1, 'user', 1000)
end;
```

These procedures should be locked until I complete the transaction with the commit statement

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE account_api AS
PROCEDURE upd_account
          (
            p_acc_id     accounts.acc_id%type
          , p_acc_name   accounts.acc_name%type
          , p_acc_amount accounts.acc_amount%type
      );
end account_api;
 /

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY account_api AS
PROCEDURE upd_account (
            p_acc_id     accounts.acc_id%type
          , p_acc_name   accounts.acc_name%type
          , p_acc_amount accounts.acc_amount%type
)
is
l_current_balance NUMBER;
l_new_balance NUMBER;

BEGIN

  SELECT acc_amount INTO l_current_balance
  FROM accounts
  WHERE acc_id = p_acc_id
  FOR UPDATE;

  l_new_balance := l_current_balance + p_acc_amount;

  IF l_new_balance < 0 THEN
      raise_application_error(-20001, 'Sorry you re overdrawn');
  END IF;

  UPDATE accounts
  SET acc_amount = l_new_balance,
      acc_name = p_acc_name
  WHERE acc_id = p_acc_id;
COMMIT;
end;
end account_api;
/
```

Comment: Title says FOR UPDATE, but there's none in SELECT statement. How come?

Comment: There is no COMMIT in your code either

Comment: I added FOR UPDATE sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The procedure seems ok to me, but I would simplify it to only one statement, and I would add an explicit ROLLBACK statement, something like this:

```
  UPDATE accounts
  SET acc_amount = acc_amount + p_acc_amount,
      acc_name = p_acc_name
  WHERE acc_id = p_acc_id
  RETURNING acc_amount INTO l_new_balance;
  IF l_new_balance < 0 THEN
      rollback;
      raise_application_error(-20001, 'Sorry you re overdrawn');
  ELSE
      commit;
  END IF;
```

There is no need to use additional `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` in order to lock the row, because UPDATE statements locks the row too. Thanks to `RETURNING INTO` clause you can retrieve a new balance, and then check it after the update, if the new balace is too low, then rollback changes, otherwise commit them.

Comment: locking starts after what? `begin
account_api.upd_account(1, 'user', 1000)
end;`

Comment: the UPDATE statement places the lock before it changes data. The lock remains active unitl either COMMIT or ROLLBACK is issued

Comment: After `begin account_api.upd_account(1, 'user', 1000) end;`
I can immediately make a second statement without any problems,
Should not the mistake be made?

Comment: I want to get a mistake when another user tries to do the update

Comment: Well, the update statement lasts a few milliseconds, so it may look like it is possible to immediately run a second transaction, but in reality both transactions are serialized by the lock - the first update locks the record, makes the change, then commits - the whole process lasts for a 10-20 miliseconds. At the same time the second transaction will wait until the record will be unlocked for 20 miliseconds, then does the second update.